# Why does Callable of ExecutorSrvice blocks the inner task? (from FP in Scala)

Tags: java, scala, parallel-processing

[image: FP in Scala Listing7.5]

In this image, They said outer Callable will block waiting for the "inner" task to compelete. What is "inner" task? and Why Should Callable waits it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner task here is `a(es)`. The "outer `Callable`" is the `new Callable` and it waits because it calls `get` on the inner task.